# ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC - Identity - Where to put custom user class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

**Simple 'best practices' question, hopefully not too opinion based:**

In my *Core 2.2 MVC* app, I want to use a custom `ApplicationUser` class to implement `IdentityUser` class.

Where should I save this class in my file structure?

I'm thinking a `Users/ApplicationUser.cs` maybe?

The MS Docs show how to implement, but don't recommend where to put the actual class. I know it's probably arbitrary, but I am not a professional programmer, so the only way for me to know these 'common knowledge' things is to ask all you real developers lol.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, IMHO, it's really opinion based. In the end, you define the structure (ends up being `namespace`s) that makes sense to your app. _Typically_ you'd map them in a `Models` folder and go from there (e.g. if you have "business models", then perhaps a `/Models/Business/` folder/namespacing structure).

Comment: Thank you, I agree with that entirely. In fact, after I made my post I thought "Maybe it should be in Models instead" and ended up putting it there. If anyone else chimes in I would love to hear whether they agree with this or have another logical place for it.

Comment: No problem. Depending on how you foresee your application(s), then _typically_ "business" models live in a separate library (for sharing with more than 1 app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just to close out the question:**

EdSf's answer is what I went with. After more research the other day I found multiple tutorials on the subject and they put their custom `ApplicationUser` classes in the `Models` folder as well.

I know it's arbitrary and opinion based, but for what it's worth, people seem to agree that the `Models` folder is a good place for the custom `ApplicationUser` class.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: EdSf, if you want to add it as an answer I will remove mine and accept yours to give you credit.